# SQL Server : moving millions of rows from one view to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 1 million rows and it has binary data stored in a `varbinary(max)` column.

I am joining this with a table with 3.6 billion rows and get 1 million rows and join to the same table twice and was able to get the records and columns I needed. The values are unique, so I didn't use the group by clause. Based on this, I created a view.

Now, I need to append the 1 million records to an existing table in the same database.

How can this be effectively achieved?

I tried SQL Server import/export wizard to append the data and 100000 records it took like 60 mins. 1 million records gets transferred in 10 hours.

How can I make this data move more efficient?

Comment: Inserting 100k rows should be pretty fast. How long does *selecting* those rows take?

Comment: Sounds like you have some significant design/performance issues. Like @TheImpaler said, inserting 100,000 rows should be a very quick task with a well designed database. Can you provide the query plan(s) and DDL of the objects (including there indexes)?

Comment: Also, why tag both [tag:sql-server-2008] and [tag:sql-server-2012]? One of those is completely unsupported and has been for almost a year. Which are you actually using?

Comment: Removed sql-server2008 tag.

Comment: I tried select top(100000)* from view and it ran for 45 mins and gave an error of out of disk space. My c: drive went from 52GB free space to 30MB and I canceled the query.  The varbinary(max) contains contents of files like txt and pdf etc.,

Answer (score -1):

The good old tried and tested way is:

INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE_NAME
SELECT [COLUMN_NAMES] FROM [SOURCE_VIEW_NAME]

I don't think there is any other faster method in SQL.